# Girlfriend from Hong Kong told interviewer for her B2 visa to the US that we were not dating

Tags: customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, interview

Will this be a problem if she tells immigration that we are dating? Will she be denied entry for this even though a B2 visa allows you to visit boyfriend/girlfriends?

Comment: Your question title says she told them you’re not dating, but your question says the opposite. Please clarify - are you referring to her visa interview or landing interview, for example?

Comment: In hong kong you need to go to an interview before getting a visa of any sort. There is where she told the interviewer than we weren't dating, but waiting to meet to decide to move forward into a relationship, which is true.  She is coming to the US in a few days and is wondering if she will be denied entry when the immigration officer asks if I am her boyfriend and she says yes. Like will he ask, welllll during your interview you said you werent, ect.

Comment: So It’s a long distance friendship and you’ve not met face to face before? Many people probably wouldn’t really describe an internet-based friendship as a ‘boyfriend/girlfriend’ scenario. Why can’t she say exactly the same thing when she arrives that she told the visa interviewer? You should edit your question to include the extra information you gave in your comment

Comment: If you lie to immigration you will be in trouble and could be permanently banned from wherever you're going. If she lies to immigration she will be in trouble and could be permanently banned from wherever she's going. Why can't she tell the immigration officer the same thing she told the interviewer?

Answer (score 4):

In a comment you state: “she told the interviewer than we weren't dating, but waiting to meet to decide to move forward into a relationship, which is true.”

That description was true at the time of her interview and will remain true on her arrival in the US. Your girlfriend should tell the Border officer exactly the same thing she told the interviewer. She should not volunteer more than this unless asked; if asked, she should stick to describing the premise and circumstances of the visit as they were described in the application.